# Form all possible combinations of groups of 2, 3, 4 from a list when the length of groups is known

Tags: python

Suppose I have tuple like `(1,2,3,4,5)`.

I want to group it like `1,1,0` that is (1 group of 2), (1 group of 3) and (0 groups of 4).

The result would be `(1,2), (3,4,5)`, `(2,3), (1,4,5)`, `(3,4), (1,2,5)`, `(4,5), (1,2,3)` `(1,3), (2,4,5)` and so on

How can I implement this? Is this is possible with `itertools`?

Comment: Will the original list contain duplicate numbers like 1,1,2,3?

Comment: How `1,1,0` translated to `(1 group of 2)`, `(1 group of 3)` and `(0 groups of 4)`

Comment: I don't understand the 110 thing. Why can't you have groups of 1, why start at 2? E.g 5 groups of 1 would be 5000?

Comment: What is your desired output? Does each element have two tuples? Or is it a flat list or tuple? Also does 1,1,0 mean group of 2 on, group of 3 on, and group of 4 off? In that case `(1 group of 2), (1 group of 3) and (0 groups of 4)` seems misleading.

Comment: @Epsi95 No there won't be any duplicate value. I will update the question  when I get some time. The answer by Alain T pretty much show what is my expected output.

Comment: @Mehul Pamale okay, then you can check my solution, it is using sets. Hope who ever downvoted it, will notice

Answer (score 1):

You can use combinations but you will still have to implement your own logic for group partitioning:

```
from itertools import combinations

def group(T,g234):
    if sum(g234) == 0: yield [];return                 # end resursion
    size = next(g for g,n in enumerate(g234,2) if n>0) # first count>0
    g234 = list(g234)                                  # remaining groups
    g234[size-2] -= 1
    for combo in combinations(range(len(T)),size):     # combine tuple indexes
        part   = tuple(T[i] for i in combo)            # subgroup of combination
        others = [v for i,v in enumerate(T) if i not in combo]  # remaining
        yield from ([part]+rest for rest in group(others,g234)) # assemble parts
```

output:

```
print(*group((1,2,3,4,5),[1,1,0]),sep="\n")
[(1, 2), (3, 4, 5)]
[(1, 3), (2, 4, 5)]
[(1, 4), (2, 3, 5)]
[(1, 5), (2, 3, 4)]
[(2, 3), (1, 4, 5)]
[(2, 4), (1, 3, 5)]
[(2, 5), (1, 3, 4)]
[(3, 4), (1, 2, 5)]
[(3, 5), (1, 2, 4)]
[(4, 5), (1, 2, 3)]

print(*group((1,2,3,4,5,6),(0,2,0)),sep="\n")
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
[(1, 2, 4), (3, 5, 6)]
[(1, 2, 5), (3, 4, 6)]
[(1, 2, 6), (3, 4, 5)]
[(1, 3, 4), (2, 5, 6)]
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
...

print(*group((1,2,3,4,5,6),(3,0,0)),sep="\n")
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
[(1, 2), (3, 5), (4, 6)]
[(1, 2), (3, 6), (4, 5)]
[(1, 2), (4, 5), (3, 6)]
[(1, 2), (4, 6), (3, 5)]
[(1, 2), (5, 6), (3, 4)]
...

print(*group((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),(1,1,1)),sep="\n")
[(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9)]
[(1, 2), (3, 4, 6), (5, 7, 8, 9)]
[(1, 2), (3, 4, 7), (5, 6, 8, 9)]
[(1, 2), (3, 4, 8), (5, 6, 7, 9)] 
...
```

**[EDIT]** Iterative version.  Uses deque as a replacement for the recursion's call stack:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import deque
def group(T,g234):
    stack = deque([(T,g234,[],None)]) #tuple, groups, parts, combo_iterator
    while stack:
        T,g234,parts,cIter = stack.pop()
        #print(len(T),g234,len(parts),bool(cIter))
        if cIter is None:
            if not sum(g234): yield parts;continue  # partition complete
            size = next(g for g,n in enumerate(g234,2) if n>0) # first count>0
            g234 = list(g234)                                  # remaining groups
            g234[size-2] -= 1
            cIter = combinations(range(len(T)),size)     # combine tuple indexes
        combo = next(cIter,None)
        if combo is None: continue
        stack.append((T,g234,parts,cIter))
        part   = tuple(T[i] for i in combo)            # subgroup of combination
        others = [v for i,v in enumerate(T) if i not in combo]  # remaining
        stack.append((others,g234,parts+[part],None))           # assemble parts
```

output:

```
for parts in group(range(1000),(500, 0,0)):
    print(parts[:3],"...",parts[-3:])

[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)] ... [(994, 995), (996, 997), (998, 999)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)] ... [(994, 995), (996, 998), (997, 999)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)] ... [(994, 995), (996, 999), (997, 998)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)] ... [(994, 995), (997, 998), (996, 999)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)] ... [(994, 995), (997, 999), (996, 998)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)] ... [(994, 995), (998, 999), (996, 997)]
...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. But T might be 1,00,000 long in length. `print(*group(range(100000),(50000, 0,0)), sep='\n')`.  Since It is throwing max recursion depth exceeded, can we have a non-recursive solution for the same ?

Comment: Added an iterative version, which I had to optimize for very large sizes but you do realize that even with only 500 groups of 2, you will get more than 10^1059 patterns. 50,000 of them would be exponentially more (I can't even compute it)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original list does not contain duplicate digits then

```py
l = {1,2,3,4,5}

[(i,j) for i in itertools.combinations(l,2) for j in itertools.combinations(l.difference(i),3)]
```

```
[((1, 2), (3, 4, 5)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 4, 5)),
 ((1, 4), (2, 3, 5)),
 ((1, 5), (2, 3, 4)),
 ((2, 3), (1, 4, 5)),
 ((2, 4), (1, 3, 5)),
 ((2, 5), (1, 3, 4)),
 ((3, 4), (1, 2, 5)),
 ((3, 5), (1, 2, 4)),
 ((4, 5), (1, 2, 3))]
```

Comment: how you came to conclusion that this is the desired output? Question seems very vague. -1 is not me by the way

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Is it possible to accept iterable, t2, t3, t4(no. of teams of 2, 3 and 4). something like `def group(l, t2, t3, t4)` and return the possible combinations?  Will this solution fail if any of t2,t3,t4 is zero because we are using nested for?